# Microsoft Authorize Endpoint - Add Dynamics 365 Business Central Permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics

I have a Multitenant application in a specific Azure AD directory.
Lets assume this application has a ClientID=123456

In order to add this application to other directories, i'm using the [Microsoft OAuth 2.0 Authorize endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

This application implements the consent framework, and the required permissions are set using the scope parameter.

For this specific application (ClientID=123456), and assuming i would need these permissions:

- openid profile email

The Authorize call would be something like:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=123456&redirect_uri=some_url&scope=email openid profile&response_mode=form_post&prompt=consent&nonce=123456778
```

If using the above, the application is correctly installed in the user Azure AD, and the permissions assigned to the application.

Now, for our specific requirements, we need this specific permission to be granted:

- https://dynamics.microsoft.com/business-central/overview/API.ReadWrite.All

[image]

Theoretically, this would be done by using the Authorize Endpoint as:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=123456&redirect_uri=some_url&scope=https://dynamics.microsoft.com/business-central/overview/API.ReadWrite.All&response_mode=form_post&prompt=consent&nonce=12345677890111
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, the Consent prompt does not request for the D365 permission at all, and is not assigned to the application.

Looking at the authorize endpoint documentation, there is nothing that indicate that this specific scope cannot be used!

What am i'm missing here, or an i doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered one Multitenant application in a specific Azure AD directory and got consent prompt when scope is `email openid profile`  with same **authorize call** as you in other directory:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=123456&redirect_uri=some_url&scope=email openid profile&response_mode=form_post&prompt=consent&nonce=123456778
```

[image]

When I accepted the above consent, this application added to other directory with **same permissions** assigned like this:

[image]

But when I change **scope** to https://dynamics.microsoft.com/business-central/overview/API.ReadWrite.All and run authorize call, I did n't get any consent prompt.

> To add **`API.ReadWrite.All`** Dynamics 365 Business Central permission, you need to change **scope** to https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default.

When I ran the **authorize call** by changing scope, I got the consent prompt for **Dynamics 365 Business Central** permission like below:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=123456&redirect_uri=some_url&scope=https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default&response_mode=form_post&prompt=consent&nonce=123456778
```

[image]

After accepting the above consent prompt,  **`API.ReadWrite.All`** **Dynamics 365 Business Central** permission added successfully like below:

[image]

In your case, https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default should be the **scope** value while adding permissions of `Application` type and make sure the other directories have **active license** supporting Dynamics 365 in it.

Comment: If i'm understanding correctly, in order to add the Graph AND the D365 permission, i will have to do TWO calls to the /authorize Endpoint? I tried to include all scopes, but i've got an error: ".default scope can't be combined with resource-specific scopes".

Comment: Yes, you have to do two calls separately. Note that, `./default` scope is used for only **Application** type permissions. If you want to add **Delegated** permissions, you can directly give scope with that [specific permission](https://i.imgur.com/Jqxybg4.png) like this `https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/Financials.ReadWrite.All`